# Open Source PyMol Conda Package: UnsatisfiableError

Tags: python, software-assistance, open-source, pymol

I'm having an issue installing the open-source version of Pymol using Anaconda on Windows. I have Python 3.8.3 installed and when I try to add the package with Conda using `conda install -c tpeulen pymol-open-source`, I get the error

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pymol-open-source -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8
```

Okay so it can't do Python 3.8? Not a problem, I'll just make a Python 3.7 virtual environment `conda create -n "py37" python=3.7.9`. Except, for some reason this still returns an error.

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pymol-open-source -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7
```

This claims that Python3.8 should work and the only version that doesn't work is 3.7! So, as a last attempt I tried switching to Python 3.6.12 and, sure enough, I got another error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pymol-open-source -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.6
```

This says only 3.7 will work, but that is clearly not the case. Am I using Conda wrong here or is there some issue with this package? How can I get the open-source PyMol installed properly?

Note: There is Incentive PyMol released by Schrodinger, which I could successfully install through Conda, but this is only a trial version. I would like to use the free version if possible.

Comment: +1. I'm not sure which software tag is the most appropriate, but I've added [tag:software-assistance] for now!

Comment: Ah, conda. A solution to a problem that was solved ~two decades ago by linux package managers, only with the joys of DLL dependency hell :D

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior with miniconda 4.9.2 running on the AWS Lambda Linux distribution with a variety of different python versions, all giving the same non-sensical version mismatch errors. Neither `tpeulen/pymol-open-source` nor `awacha/pymol-open-source` work, but `schrodinger/pymol` does. The open source versions install fine with the same version of miniconda on Mac OS X. Weird!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround to get open source PyMol installed on Windows. Christoph Gohlke at the University of California has a large library of [precompiled Python wheel files](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pymol) of various scientific packages, including PyMol. I was able to find a Windows version for Python 3.8 `pymol‑2.5.0a0‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` and after downloading this file, I was able to install PyMol using pip `python -m pip install pymol‑2.5.0a0‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`.

As mentioned on the [PyMol wiki](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Windows_Install), I also had to pip install the `pyqt5` package to get the graphical window working. I'm still puzzled why Conda didn't work, but at least it's possible to access this program on Windows.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Linux its better if you install such packages using the apt-get method.

> apt-get install pymol

I've encountered a similar error while installing MatPlotLib through conda.

For more info you can follow this link:

https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Linux_Install

Hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 I realized I left out that I'm on Windows, but I have WSL2 so this is also a helpful option. Answers for other operating are certainly welcome.

Comment: +1. The original question didn't specify the operating system, so a Linux solution is a fair answer. If someone else gives an answer specific to Windows that would be even more helpful to the user, though I may point out that most users here probably use Linux (certainly there's been some trouble in getting help here for people using the Mac OS: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-operating-system, one question is unanswered and one question has an answer only from the original person that asked the question).

Comment: +1, but Is there any source for better to use apt-get? I've been using Anaconda for a long time. I'd prefer to not have to use another way to install packages (e.g. there is already pip, conda, and now this)